# How can I make this dropdown-menu not close itself after selecting an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using this NavBar that contains a dropdown menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/rvetgyen/

```js
/**
 * Created by Kupletsky Sergey on 17.10.14.
 *
 * Material Sidebar (Profile menu)
 * Tested on Win8.1 with browsers: Chrome 37, Firefox 32, Opera 25, IE 11, Safari 5.1.7
 * You can use this sidebar in Bootstrap (v3) projects. HTML-markup like Navbar bootstrap component will make your work easier.
 * Dropdown menu and sidebar toggle button works with JQuery and Bootstrap.min.js
 */

// Sidebar toggle
//
// -------------------
$(document).ready(function() {
  var overlay = $('.sidebar-overlay');

  $('.sidebar-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
    sidebar.toggleClass('open');
    if ((sidebar.hasClass('sidebar-fixed-left') || sidebar.hasClass('sidebar-fixed-right')) && sidebar.hasClass('open')) {
      overlay.addClass('active');
    } else {
      overlay.removeClass('active');
    }
  });

  overlay.on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('#sidebar').removeClass('open');
  });

});

// Sidebar constructor
//
// -------------------
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
  var sidebarHeader = $('#sidebar .sidebar-header');
  var sidebarImg = sidebarHeader.css('background-image');
  var toggleButtons = $('.sidebar-toggle');

  // Hide toggle buttons on default position
  toggleButtons.css('display', 'none');
  $('body').css('display', 'table');


  // Sidebar position
  $('#sidebar-position').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    sidebar.removeClass('sidebar-fixed-left sidebar-fixed-right sidebar-stacked').addClass(value).addClass('open');
    if (value == 'sidebar-fixed-left' || value == 'sidebar-fixed-right') {
      $('.sidebar-overlay').addClass('active');
    }
    // Show toggle buttons
    if (value != '') {
      toggleButtons.css('display', 'initial');
      $('body').css('display', 'initial');
    } else {
      // Hide toggle buttons
      toggleButtons.css('display', 'none');
      $('body').css('display', 'table');
    }
  });

  // Sidebar theme
  $('#sidebar-theme').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    sidebar.removeClass('sidebar-default sidebar-inverse sidebar-colored sidebar-colored-inverse').addClass(value)
  });

  // Header cover
  $('#sidebar-header').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $('.sidebar-header').removeClass('header-cover').addClass(value);

    if (value == 'header-cover') {
      sidebarHeader.css('background-image', sidebarImg)
    } else {
      sidebarHeader.css('background-image', '')
    }
  });
});

/**
 * Created by Kupletsky Sergey on 08.09.14.
 *
 * Add JQuery animation to bootstrap dropdown elements.
 */

(function($) {
  var dropdown = $('.dropdown');

  // Add slidedown animation to dropdown
  dropdown.on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
  });

  // Add slideup animation to dropdown
  dropdown.on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
})(jQuery);



(function(removeClass) {

  jQuery.fn.removeClass = function(value) {
    if (value && typeof value.test === "function") {
      for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        var elem = this[i];
        if (elem.nodeType === 1 && elem.className) {
          var classNames = elem.className.split(/\s+/);

          for (var n = classNames.length; n--;) {
            if (value.test(classNames[n])) {
              classNames.splice(n, 1);
            }
          }
          elem.className = jQuery.trim(classNames.join(" "));
        }
      }
    } else {
      removeClass.call(this, value);
    }
    return this;
  }

})(jQuery.fn.removeClass);
```

```css
@import"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin,cyrillic";

/* -- import Roboto Font ---------------------------- */

/* -- import Material Icons Font -------------------- */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Design Iconic Font';
  src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.eot?v=1.0');
  src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.eot?#iefix&v=1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff?v=1.0') format('woff'), url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.ttf?v=1.0') format('truetype'), url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.svg?v=1.0#Material-Design-Iconic-Font') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[class^="mds-"],
[class*=" mds-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1'Material Design Iconic Font';
  font-size: inherit;
  speak: none;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.mds {
  line-height: inherit;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.mds-inbox:before {
  content: "\f10c";
}
.mds-star:before {
  content: "\f2e5";
}
.mds-send:before {
  content: "\f119";
}
.mds-drafts:before {
  content: "\f107";
}
.mds-arrow-back:before {
  content: "\f297";
}
.mds-arrow-forward:before {
  content: "\f298";
}
/* -- You can use this sidebar in Bootstrap (v3) projects. HTML-markup like Navbar bootstrap component will make your work easier. -- */

/* -- Box model ------------------------------- */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* -- Demo style ------------------------------- */

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.sidebar-overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1034;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0 linear 0.4s, opacity 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -moz-transition: visibility 0 linear 0.4s, opacity 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition: visibility 0 linear 0.4s, opacity 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.sidebar-overlay.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}
.top-bar {
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
/* -- Google typography ------------------------------- */

.headline {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: #212121;
  text-transform: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
}
.subhead {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: #212121;
  text-transform: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
}
/* -- Bootstrap-like style ------------------------------- */

.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
/* -- Constructor style ------------------------------- */

.constructor {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
}
.sidebar,
.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.sidebar-stacked.open + .wrapper .constructor {
  margin-left: 280px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-stacked.open + .wrapper .constructor {
    margin-left: 240px;
  }
}
/* -- Sidebar style ------------------------------- */

.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
}
.sidebar:before,
.sidebar:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.sidebar:after {
  clear: both;
}
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-header {
  position: relative;
  height: 157.5px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-header.header-cover {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-header:hover .sidebar-toggle {
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: none;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-toggle:before,
.sidebar .sidebar-toggle:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-toggle:after {
  clear: both;
}
.sidebar .icon-material-sidebar-arrow:before {
  content: "\e610";
}
.sidebar .sidebar-image img {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  margin: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 56px;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 500;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-brand:hover,
.sidebar .sidebar-brand:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-brand .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  top: 24px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-brand .sidebar-badge {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 12px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-brand:hover,
.sidebar .sidebar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-badge {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-badge.badge-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-divider,
.sidebar .sidebar-nav .divider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-text {
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 56px;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 500;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-text:hover,
.sidebar .sidebar-text:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-text .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  top: 24px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-text .sidebar-badge {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 12px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 16px;
  min-width: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-icon:before,
.sidebar .sidebar-icon:after {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 56px;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 500;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  top: 24px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a .sidebar-badge {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 12px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.sidebar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-header {
  background-color: #eceff1;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-toggle {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-brand {
  color: #DEDEDE;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-brand:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-brand:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-badge {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-divider,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav .divider {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-text {
  color: #212121;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a i {
  color: #757575;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li:hover > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a:hover {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li:hover > a i,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a:hover i {
  color: #757575;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li:focus > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li:focus > a i,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a:focus i {
  color: #757575;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .open > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .active > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #e0e0e0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: #212121;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #cecece;
  color: #212121;
}
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-280px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-280px, 0, 0);
}
.sidebar.open {
  min-width: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.sidebar-fixed-left,
.sidebar-fixed-right,
.sidebar-stacked {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1035;
}
.sidebar-stacked {
  left: 0;
}
.sidebar-fixed-left {
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
.sidebar-fixed-right {
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(280px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(280px, 0, 0);
}
.sidebar-fixed-right.open {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.sidebar-fixed-right .icon-material-sidebar-arrow:before {
  content: "\e614";
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar.open {
    min-width: 240px;
    width: 240px;
  }
  .sidebar .sidebar-header {
    height: 135px;
  }
  .sidebar .sidebar-image img {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Overlay for fixed sidebar -->
<div class="sidebar-overlay"></div>
<!-- Material sidebar -->
<aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar sidebar-default open" role="navigation">
  <!-- Sidebar header -->
  <div class="sidebar-header header-cover" style="background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-2RewSLZUzRg/U-9o6SD4M6I/AAAAAAAADIE/voax99AbRx0/s1600/14%2B-%2B1%2B%281%29.jpg);">
    <!-- Top bar -->
    <div class="top-bar"></div>
    <!-- Sidebar toggle button -->
    <button type="button" class="sidebar-toggle"> <i class="icon-material-sidebar-arrow"></i>

    </button>
    <!-- Sidebar brand image -->
    <div class="sidebar-image">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/atom_profile_01.jpg">
    </div>
    <!-- Sidebar brand name --> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="sidebar-brand" href="#settings-dropdown">
            john.doe@gmail.com
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>

  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar navigation -->
  <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <ul id="settings-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li> <a href="#" tabindex="-1">
                        Profile
                    </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#" tabindex="-1">
                        Settings
                    </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#" tabindex="-1">
                        Help
                    </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#" tabindex="-1">
                        Exit
                    </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="sidebar-icon md-inbox"></i>
        Inbox
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="sidebar-icon md-star"></i>
        Starred
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="sidebar-icon md-send"></i>
        Sent Mail
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="sidebar-icon md-drafts"></i>
        Drafts
      </a>

    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown"> <a class="ripple-effect dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                All Mail
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li> <a href="#" tabindex="-1">
                        Social
                        <span class="sidebar-badge">12</span>
                    </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#" tabindex="-1">
                        Promo
                        <span class="sidebar-badge">0</span>
                    </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">
                Trash
                <span class="sidebar-badge">3</span>
            </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">
                Spam
                <span class="sidebar-badge">456</span>
            </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">
                Follow Up
                <span class="sidebar-badge badge-circle">i</span>
            </a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Sidebar divider -->
  <!-- <div class="sidebar-divider"></div> -->
  <!-- Sidebar text -->
  <!-- <div class="sidebar-text">Text</div> -->
</aside>
```

I want to make it in a way that if you click in "All Mail" and then "Social" for example, the "All Mail" dropdown will still be open and the only way to close it is clicking again in "All Mail".

To ilustrate better what I trying to achieve as result is something similar to this sidebar:

https://material.angularjs.org/#/

After you select a category you can navigate through the elements and the dropdown (if I can call it like that) don't hide.

Comment: put your code on jsfiddle.net. It would be easy to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().parent().siblings(".dropdown-toggle").show();
});
```

Comment: It is hiding my whole dropdown list after clicling in an option.

Comment: @HugoNakamura On clicking it...ideally what it should happen?

Comment: I probably wasnt clear on my post, sorry. I want the dropdown to remain open like this: https://material.angularjs.org/#/

Comment: @HugoNakamura I have made changes with respect to you. Can you check it?

Comment: thank you but it still closes after clicking anywhere.